# Unable to authorize with CanCan and Authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic, roles, cancan

I'm trying to implement roles with Authlogic to restrict controller access in my rails app. As soon as I implement it with load_and_authorize and filter_resource_access, I am unable to access the controller under any role.
In my User model, I have a role field, which has_many roles_users which points to the Roles model. So User 1 is 'admin', has a role assignment 1, which links into role 1 which is 'admin'.

## ability.rb

```
include CanCan::Ability

def initialize(user)
 user ||= User.new # guest user
 can :read, InstallQuote
 can :create, InstallQuote
 if user.role? :admin
  can :manage, :all
 end
```

## application_controller.rb

```
helper :all
protect_from_forgery # See ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection for details
helper_method :current_user_session, :current_user  

rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
 flash[:error] = exception.message
   redirect_back_or_default(root_path)
 end

before_filter { |c| Authorization.current_user = c.current_user }
filter_parameter_logging :password, :password_confirmation 

protected
  def current_user_session
    return @current_user_session if defined?(@current_user_session)
    @current_user_session = UserSession.find
  end

def current_user
  return @current_user if defined?(@current_user)
  @current_user = current_user_session && current_user_session.user
end
```

## clients_controller.rb

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController
# before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:edit, :update, :show, :index]

load_and_authorize_resource # For declarative authorization
filter_resource_access

# belongs_to :company
# before_filter :require_user, :only => [:edit, :update, :index, :destroy]
# before_filter :admin_user, :only => :destroy
helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction
before_filter :correct_user, :only => [:edit, :update, :show, :index]
```

## user.rb

```
acts_as_authentic
has_many :roles_users
has_many :roles, :through => :roles_users
before_create :setup_role
attr_accessible :email, :login, :first_name, :last_name, :role_id, :password, :password_confirmation, :active
```

(I've commented out old code I don't want to ditch just yet).

Anyone know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you're logged in and `user.role? :admin` returns true.

If it's not the reason, you can debug directly in console:

```
user = User.first
ability = Ability.new(user)
ability.can? :read, Client
```